# IE Doesn't support forEach even with Polyfill.

Tags: javascript

I have added the forEach polyfill to the top of my JavaScript file however Internet Explorer is still saying that it doesn't support the function.

I basically want to loop over the results of a querySelector however I do use forEach on some other array objects in my script.

This all works fine on Chrome.

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.18
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {

  Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback/*, thisArg*/) {

    var T, k;
    if (this === null) {
      throw new TypeError('this is null or not defined');
    }
    var O = Object(this);
    var len = O.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
    }
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      T = arguments[1];
    }
    k = 0;
    while (k < len) {
      var kValue;
      if (k in O) {
        kValue = O[k];
        callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
      }
      k++;
    }
  };
}

(function() {

  var instance = null,
      container;

  // Constructor
  this.MarvLightbox = function() {
    // Initialise plugin
    this.init();
  };

  // Initilise the plugin
  MarvLightbox.prototype.init = function() {

    document.querySelectorAll('[data-click]').forEach(function(e) {
      e.addEventListener('click', [clickevent]);
    });

  };

}());
```

Shouldn't adding the polyfill fix this issue with IE?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, not an array.

Comment: [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from?v=control)

Comment: @Emissary very bad suggestion - that's ES6 and doesn't work in IE

Comment: @baao it has a perfectly good polyfill too - it's best practice to code in a way that dropping legacy support doesn't require further changes to your application code.

Comment: there is a separate polyfill for NodeList https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are adding a prototype to the `Array` object and try to use it on a `NodeList` (which is what querySelectorAll returns instead of an array), that won't work. Make an Array out of the node List, or use

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-click]'), function (e) {
    // your code
});
```

Comment: This is really really helpful. Not sure why polyfill has don't have this support.

Comment: this just saved my life, also tried to polyfill this problem to no avail

Answer (score 20):

Another way to make IE9+ support `forEach`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <span class="demo">See me.</span>
    <script>
        // Function to make IE9+ support forEach:
        if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
            NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
        }

        // Works with Nodelists (i.e. HTMLcollections):
        var demos = document.querySelectorAll('.demo');
        demos.forEach(function(item) {
            item.style.color = 'red';
        });

        // As well as with Arrays:
        var gherkins = ['gher1', 'gher2', 'gher3'];
        gherkins.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log(item);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested in IE11, and according to its emulate function, also works in 10 and 9 (not 8).

Comment: I prefer this solution, it prevents having to rewrite an existing codebase

Comment: Tested and approved; works wonders for a quick fix on IE! Thanks Frank!

Comment: If you are using documents.getElementsByName() you can do the same fix above but for HtmlCollection instead of NodeList

Comment: @MeatPopsicle - That has nothing to do with the question. The question was how to get forEach to work in IE, so that you don't have to use the more complicated loop method every time.

Comment: Well I arrived at this post because I had the same error except I was querying for DOM elements using getElementsByName instead of querySelector so if you polyfill one to support IE then I imagine you probably want to polyfil the other too. Anyway, I was just trying to help